# Google Maps configuration in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net web application, how can i configuration google map, Is there any free resource. How can i start, can any one help me thank you.

Comment: start by posting your codes.

Answer (score 0):

Google maps is all javascript. You can use it in ASP.NET as you would any other javascript.

There are plenty of free tutorials online.

http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/default.asp

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/

http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=62843

try some geocoding

http://www.wikihow.com/Geocode-an-Address-in-Google-Maps-Javascript

Have fun.

Comment: Hi spryce, i go through the w3schools it is good, but can i get the boundaries of a particular district in the state like that